# Unable to load code at confirming login success

Tags: php

I am a beginner at using PHP. Sometime ago I bought this book PHP and MySQL in easysteps and I started learning PHP. Everything was ok till now (I am almost at the end), when I encountered a problem which I don't know how to resolve.

This is the error it gives me.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\home.php on line 19

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start() ;
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ]))
{
    require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ;
    load() ;
}
$page_title = 'Home' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;
echo "<h1>Home</h1>
<p>You are now logged in,
{ $_SESSION[ 'first_name'  ] } { $_SESSION[ 'last_name' ] } 
</p>" ;
echo '<p>
<a href="forum.php">Forum</a> |
<a href="shop.php">Shop</a> |
<a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a>
</p>' ;
include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help. Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your code include the numbers at the beginning of each line?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following line

```
{$_SESSION['first_name']} {$_SESSION['last_name' ]}
```

Make sure there are no spaces

Comment: That shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It does matter as stated in the PHP docs "Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {"

Comment: Sorry Markus, you're right. I just did a bad paste in my test file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start() ;
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ]))
{
    require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ;
    load() ;
}
$page_title = 'Home' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;
echo "<h1>Home</h1>
<p>You are now logged in,".$_SESSION[ 'first_name'  ] ." ". $_SESSION[ 'last_name' ]."</p>" ;
echo '<p>
<a href="forum.php">Forum</a> |
<a href="shop.php">Shop</a> |
<a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a>
</p>' ;
include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. I didn't know that there should be no spaces between $ and other stuff, so great help. Tried both corrections, Marcus and parveen, both don't give me an error anymore ... still doesnt show whats supposed to show, but i belive that is a problem with another code. So thank you very much for your help. :)